# Indexing Foreign keys

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I index a foreign key in Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE reftable (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)

CREATE TABLE mytable (id INT NOT NULL, ref INT NOT NULL)

ALTER TABLE mytable
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_mytable_ref_reftable
FOREIGN KEY (ref) REFERENCES reftable (id)

CREATE INDEX ix_mytable_ref ON mytable (ref)
```

The column in another table (the one you are referencing) must be a `PRIMARY KEY` or have a `UNIQUE` constraint defined on it, which means it already has an index.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot index the foreign key constraint itself, but you can index the columns the foreign key is defined on.

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: sorry... that was wht was inteded :)